# YoY Calculations on Rows in Same Column SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

```
Business Unit |  Date  | Sales
North America | 5/1/17 | 5,000
North America | 4/1/17 | 4,000
North America | 3/1/17 | 3,000
North America | 2/1/17 | 2,000
North America | 1/1/17 | 1,000
          ............
North America | 5/1/16 | 4,000
North America | 4/1/16 | 3,000
North America | 3/1/16 | 2,000
North America | 2/1/16 | 2,000
North America | 1/1/16 |   500
         ............
Asia          | 5/1/17 | 5,000
Asia          | 4/1/17 | 2,000
Asia          | 3/1/17 | 1,000
Asia          | 2/1/17 | 3,000
Asia          | 1/1/17 | 1,500
          ............
Asia          | 5/1/16 | 4,000
Asia          | 4/1/16 | 2,000
Asia          | 3/1/16 |   500
Asia          | 2/1/16 | 1,500
Asia          | 1/1/16 | 1,000
```

Each month consists of all 38, 30, or 31 days - however for ease of the example I just showed the first days in the data above.

Below is an example of the output I am looking to achieve:

```
Business Unit |  Date  | Sales | Year over Year Change |
North America | 5/1/17 | 5,000 |           25%         |
North America | 4/1/17 | 4,000 |           33%         |
North America | 3/1/17 | 3,000 |           50%         |
North America | 2/1/17 | 2,000 |            0%         |
North America | 1/1/17 | 1,000 |           50%         |
          ............
North America | 5/1/16 | 4,000 |           xx%         |
North America | 4/1/16 | 3,000 |           xx%         |
North America | 3/1/16 | 2,000 |           xx%         |
North America | 2/1/16 | 2,000 |           xx%         |
North America | 1/1/16 |   500 |           xx%         |
         ............
Asia          | 5/1/17 | 5,000 |           25%         |
Asia          | 4/1/17 | 2,000 |            0%         |
Asia          | 3/1/17 | 1,000 |          100%         |
Asia          | 2/1/17 | 3,000 |          100%         |
Asia          | 1/1/17 | 1,500 |           50%         |
          ............
Asia          | 5/1/16 | 4,000 |           xx%         |
Asia          | 4/1/16 | 2,000 |           xx%         |
Asia          | 3/1/16 |   500 |           xx%         |
Asia          | 2/1/16 | 1,500 |           xx%         |
Asia          | 1/1/16 | 1,000 |           xx%         |
```

As mentioned above, this data is daily and goes back multiple years. Thanks so much in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
Select coalesce(lastyear.[Business Unit], currentyear.[Business Unit]) as BusinessUnit, currentyear.[date], lastyear.[date] as [LastYear Date],
    Format((1-(lastyear.Sales*1.0)/currentyear.Sales), 'p') 
from #yoydata lastyear
left join #yoydata currentyear
on lastyear.[date] = dateadd(yy,-1,currentyear.[date])
and lastyear.[Business Unit] = currentyear.[Business Unit]
```

Comment: thanks a ton that is super close. It seems that the actual calculation column is off though. When I plug it into my actual data it pulls the correct dates, however it is not calculating the year over year changed based on the last year date

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: What issue u r getting?

Comment: Yep you are correct, copy paste mistake  and lastyear.[Business Unit] = currentyear.[Business Unit]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(lastyear.[bu], currentyear.[bu]) AS BusinessUnit
    , currentyear.[dt]
    , lastyear.[dt]                             AS [LastYear Date]
    , Format((1-(lastyear.Sales*1.0)/currentyear.Sales), 'p') 
FROM
    #yoydata lastyear 
        LEFT JOIN #yoydata currentyear  ON lastyear.[dt] = dateadd(yy,-1,currentyear.[dt]) 
                                            AND lastyear.bu = currentyear.bu
```

Comment: previous answer was just missing the join on the business unit.